# Checking if sections of a dataframe row are the same in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe that has some repetitions in it. They are in a particular number of column indices for each row:

```
df_in

0   1   2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19...
1   3   4    6    0    2    0    3    0    2    0    3    4    5    6    2    4    5    6    2...
.
.
```

In `row 1` from index `4-7` there's a repetition of `[0, 2, 0, 3]` from indices `8-11` and then from index `12-15` there is a repetition of `[4, 5, 6, 2]` from `16-19`.

What I need is to detect if every `4 numbers` in every row is equal and if so delete one of those repetitions from the DataFrame.

The output would be:

```
df_out

0   1   2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11...
1   3   4    6    0    2    0    3    4    5    6    2...
.
.
```

The psudo code would be something like:

```
for index in range(4, len(df_in.columns)):
      if bool((df_in.iloc[:, index] == (df_in.iloc[:, index+4]).all()) == True:

             remove either df_in.iloc[:, index] or df_in.iloc[:, index]+4 and keep one

      if bool((df_in.iloc[:, index] == (df_in.iloc[:, index+4]).all()) == False:

             keep df_in.iloc[:, index]
```

Is there an easy way to get this done?

Comment: should it be `for index in range(4, len(df_in.columns), 4):`?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a crazy solution. Main idea is to check for duplication using python's `hash` function:

```
# original data frame
df = pd.DataFrame([1,3,4,6,0,2,0,3,0,2,0,3,4,5,6,2,4,5,6,2]).T

# we will create hash on tuple of every subsequence of length 4
sub4hash = df.iloc[0].rolling(4).apply(lambda s: hash(tuple(s))).shift(-3)

# start of duplication:
dup_start = sub4hash.duplicated()

# and we want all 4, so rolling again:
markers = dup_start.rolling(4).sum().gt(0)

# finally:
df.loc[:, ~markers]

      0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    12    13    14    15
--  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ----  ----  ----  ----
 0    1    3    4    6    0    2    0    3     4     5     6     2
```